# Is there a way to tell if x-sendfile has started?

Tags: php, x-sendfile

I think the subject says it all.

I want a download to start when a page is loaded and then for the body of the page to load once the script is sure the download has commenced.

Comment: As long as it is done by another http-request - you cannot do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others looking for an answer, this isn't really it, but it solved my problem of doing hidden digital downloads

Simple IPN Script

Created By: Iszuddin Ismail

Website: http://www.minisitegallery.com/blog/simple-ipn.html